# What is the Infinite Pigeonhole Principle?

Tags: combinatorics, pigeonhole-principle

I saw this [problem](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1231860) on AOPS and, at the end of pi$37$'s proof, he mentioned something about the infinite pigeonhole principle. Can someone explain what he means by this?

Comment: I didn't dive too deeply into the proof, but I think the idea is that if you put an infinite number of balls into a finite number of boxes then you can conclude that there is a box with an infinite number of balls in it.

Comment: @MatthewDaly It is the other way around, if finitely many pigeons are distributed among infinitely many holes then there are infinitely many empty holes, see [Tao's infinite pigeonhole principle: "All sequences have constant subsequences"](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3444254/152568)

Answer (score 8):

If you have infinitely many pigeons and put them in finitely many pigeonholes, then some pigeonhole must contain infinitely many pigeons.